# Getting extra character while caputuring system call output in c

Tags: c++, pipe, popen

i am capturing system call output using pipe.
Command i am running is the following :-

```
ps -ef | grep "/home/code/service" | grep 14011 | awk '{print $NF}'
```

when i execute above command on command prompt it give me one integer value say **197**.

when i execute same command using pipe , i am getting the following :-

```
$NF}'
$NF}'
197
```

Above output order is in random order , so it could be the follwing :-

```
$NF}'
197
$NF}'
```

I am using similar code( by waqas ) mentioned in below link  :-

[How to execute a command and get output of command within C++ using POSIX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478898/how-to-execute-a-command-and-get-output-of-command-within-c)

I am passing command to pipe using following way :-

```
std::stringstream sstr ;

sstr<<"ps -ef | ";
sstr<<"grep \"/home/code/service/\" | grep ";
sstr<<ppid;
sstr<<" | awk \'{print $NF}\'";

FILE* pipe = popen((sstr.str()).c_str(), "r");
```

Comment: Please show us how **exactly** you are calling this from C.

Comment: Note that `std::stringstream` is just a massive syntax error in C.  You seem to be using C++, not C.  If you don't know which language you're programming in, it is not surprising you can't write good code in it.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Now please also show us how you pull and print the result of the command issued via `popen()`.

Comment: in same way mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/478898/how-to-execute-a-command-and-get-output-of-command-within-c link